# Spring DI - Non-managed-object custom resolution

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I have the following bean / constructor definitions:

```
@Configuration
class Configuration {
    @Bean
    public List<Something> getSomethings(MyFancyStuff stuff, @Autowired Bar bar) {
        //...
    }
}

@Component
class SomeOtherThing {
    public SomeOtherThing(MyFancyStuff stuff, @Autowired Bar bar) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Is it possible to extends dependency resolution to provide a custom resolver when a specific class or annotation is found for a given parameter? I looked at `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` and `InstantiationAwareBeanPostProcessor` but nothing seemed to help me write my own value provider.

As a context: I implemented a custom scope which creates many instances of a given bean for each configuration object it has. I want to pass this configuration object to the bean-creation-process of said scope without adding it to the application context. I don't want to add it to the application context because it is an object which no other object should be able to obtain through dependency injection. I need to extend the DI-process of spring because I want to support field injection, constructor injection and bean factory-methods like the shown `getSomethings`

note: this is not about automatic value conversion of SpringMVC request parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Conditional Annotation

```
  @Bean(name="dataSource")
  @Conditional(value=DevCondition.class)
  public Util getSource1() {
      return new DevUtil();
  }

  @Bean(name="dataSource")
  @Conditional(ProdCondition.class)
  public Util getSource2() {
      return new ProdUtil();
  }
```

you can also create bean based on property value using @Profile

Comment: this creates a singleton bean on context startup, i need a dynamic bean registration that is not available in the global appctx

Comment: then why do you want to create a bean.. You can create your own object and dont annotate with spring annotations. This object will not be available in the application context.

Comment: all beans with my custom annotation should be able to obtain a specific value that is associated with its instantiation. The custom scoped object is a spring bean, the value I want to supply to said beans is not a bean - Making the value I want to pass a spring bean would mean any bean could obtain it, which is not what I want